# Angular2 Error -- The server has not found ... http://localhost:1595/angular2/http

Tags: http, angular

I am trying to get my first Angluar2 app running, and for some reason am getting the error "The server has not found `http://localhost/angular2/http`".

Other angular stuff is working fine, it is just a problem with the http module.

I have imported the module like this:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'; // My top level component
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

And included the relevant script tags:

```
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

But still no joy. Any suggestions as to what I am missing? The error message seems to be looking for the module as a file rather than loading it from the existing modules created by the script tags. But I am new to this so a little confused, since the "from" part of the "import" statement seems to mean different things -- either an existing module or the filename in which it is located.

There might be some other configuration that I am missing, but I am at a loss to where it might be.

If it matters this is Angular2 in the context of a Microsoft MVC 6 web application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing `http.dev.js` in your index.html:

`<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js"></script>`

I should also not this has changed in the new release candidate. I suggest you download the newer version of the [quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and take a look at that to get you started on the right track.